# Lost AUT connection between test cases in Squish

Tags: python, qt, automation, squish

We are using Squish for QT in Python. For my tests I need to start application before execute test suite and close when execution is done.
To achieve this I do next steps:

1. Register AUT in Squish IDE
2. Start AUT via `subprocess.Popen()`
3. Attach to the application using `attachToApplication()`
4. Run test suite (multiple test cases)

First test case works fine but on the second test case I get an error "Lost connection to AUT". Do I need to attach to the application in every test case or is it possible to pass application context to the next test cases?

Comment: Yes, each test case needs to attach to the desired AUTs explicitly. (Note that each test case is executed by a new squishrunner instance, therefore passing objects that live inside the test script interpreter is not possible.) If you start the AUT via subprocess.Popen() in the test script, double check that it survives the end of the test case execution. The error message implies that the AUT got attached to and then the AUT quit (or got killed).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, it is much clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to 'attach to AUT' at the beginning of each test case in your test suite. Which means, the third step you have mentioned above needs to be done at the beginning of each test case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Thanks for the improvement point!, Rephrased. the question is about Squish GUI tester and the answer is to attach to AUT (step3 mentioned by the asker himself) at the beginning of each test case.